# Pointwise Limit of $f_n = \frac{x^n}{2+x^{2n}}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n = \frac{x^n}{2+x^{2n}}$. What is the pointwise limit of this sequence of functions on $(0,1)$? We cannot say anything about $\frac{1}{x^n}$ since $|x| < 1$.

Comment: You're right, ignore my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you get that $$x^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0.$$ The same way, $$x^{2n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\Rightarrow 2 + x^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}2.$$

Now, combining the two results, we get: $$\frac{x^n}{2 + x^{2n}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac{0}{2 + 0} = 0.$$

Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, thanks. A shame that I screwed this question up on my quiz just now!